# Stack Implementation with o(1)

Tags: java, generics, stack

I am trying to implement kind of Stack, which has push(), pop(), getMaxSoFar().
It should be executed o(1) time. However, I got an error in push(T value), and I don't know why. The error message said the operator ">=" is not defined in the type of T. I just wanted to check the code so I put int type instead of  then it worked.

```
class FastMaxStack<T>
{    
private Stack<T> stack;
private Stack<T> maxStack;

public FastMaxStack()
{
    stack = new Stack();
    maxStack = new Stack();
}

public void push(T value)
{
    if(maxStack.isEmpty())
    {
        maxStack.push(value);
    }
    else if(value >= maxStack.peek()) 
    {
        maxStack.push(value);
    }

    stack.push(value);
}

public T pop()
{
    maxStack.pop();
    return  stack.pop(); 
}

public T getMaxSoFar()
{
    return maxStack.peek(); 
}
}
```

Comment: Look into Comparable. You want your T to be `T extends Comparable<T>`, which basically means "a type T that's comparable to itself."

Comment: If you want to compare any `T` value, you need `T` to implement `Comparable<T>`, so you can call `compareTo()`, instead of trying to use the numeric only `>=` operator on objects.

Comment: As an aside I’m not sure it will work. What happens if I push 5 and 3 and then pop both again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `push` method is assuming that the `>=` operator is supported for every conceivable type `T`.  However, that operator is only supported for numeric types.

Perhaps you should define your class to operate for integers only, and not any data type.

On the other hand, perhaps you could implement your class for all [`Comparables`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

```
class FastMaxStack<Comparable<T>>
{
   //etc...  
}
```

Comment: You are right. I amended my code only for the case dealing with int type. Thank you so much! I did not realize that my push() method above is not valid. I fixed it!

Comment: public void push(int value)
 {
  int max = 0;
  
  if(maxStack.isEmpty())
  {
   max = value;
  }
  else
  {
   max = (int) maxStack.peek(); 
  }
  
  if(max > value)
  {
   maxStack.push(max);
  }
  else
  {
   maxStack.push(value);
  }
  
  
  stack.push(value);
 }

Answer (score 0):

*(too long for a comment)*

There is another problem.

`push` always pushes on `stack`, but only pushes on `maxStack` if the value is at least as large as the top. So far, so good.

But `pop` always pops from both. Two problems:

- Even if you pop as many times as you push, there can be an `EmptyStackException` if `maxStack` does not have enough elements (which will happen if you don't push values in increasing order).
- Even if there is no exception, the value of `getMaxSoFar` won't be correct. As I understand what you are trying to do, `maxStack` is supposed to hold in top the max element of the stack in its current state. But imagine you push a value smaller than top, `maxStack` is not updated, and if you pop (from both then), the max is lost in `maxStack`. But it's still here in `stack`.

Comment: I think you could be raising some valid points here but it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I know. I'm aware that this might downvoted, but I think it's worth letting the OP know the syntax is not the only problem in this program.

Comment: The points are certainly valid. I tried to add the same in a comment, but of course it is not as clear as this — I hesitate to call it answer, sorry.

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed, I intended to write a comment but it's too long.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! All the help from you guys is truly helpful. I fixed the push() method and it seems that it works!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut public void push(int value) { int max = 0; if(maxStack.isEmpty()) { max = value; } else { max = (int) maxStack.peek(); } if(max > value) { maxStack.push(max); } else { maxStack.push(value); } stack.push(value); }

Comment: @OleV.V. With this both stacks have the same number of elements (the max is duplicated if necessary). So the two bugs mentioned above are solved. The price to pay is there are twice as many elements as in a standard stack.

Comment: I see it now. It’s just because code pasted into a comment is unreadable, sorry.